# Clojure - functional relaxation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, clojure, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement ragdoll physics in Clojure. My model has a sequence *x* of multidimensional coordinates and a matrix *M* of distance constraints, needed in one part of the relaxation algorithm.

The general idea is that if a matrix entry *m_ij* is different from zero I have to modify coordinates *x_i* and *x_j* in a way such that their distance is equal to *M_ij*. Assume that each *x_n* is a 2D/3D coordinate and I know how to to the correct calculations.

Now, as each entry of *M* affects two coordinates I can't think of a way to use `map` or `reduce` to properly iterate over the coordinates. I could maybe put two calls of `loop, recur` inside each other to emulate an imperative, but I hope there's a better way (especially as it leads to code that looks really confusing).

Do you know of a functional way to iterate over a two-dimensional matrix and modify multiple vector entries in the process?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is mapping over pairs of adjacent points, as opposed to point values, and then reassembling those results.

Comment: Have you considered `for` ?  `(for [x (range 10) y (range 5)] ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `reduce-kv` captures the essence of this pattern well:

```
(reduce-kv (fn [x' [i j] d] ;; x' — accumulator (vector of coordinates)
                            ;; [i j] — Matrix coordinates
                            ;; d — Matrix value (distance)
             (let [[x'ᵢ x'ⱼ] (update-distance (nth x' i)
                                              (nth x' j)
                                              d)]
               (assoc x' i x'ᵢ j x'ⱼ)))
           x  ;; Initial coordinates
           M) ;; Matrix
```

A few notes:

- `update-distance` calculates a new pair of coordinates from an initial pair of coordinates and distance
- We use `assoc` to "update" `x`.  So `x` should be a vector (any associative would work, but a vector seems to be the natural choice.
- The matrix `M` must satisfy the `clojure.core.protocols/IKVReduce` protocol.
  If it doesn't, you can either provide an implementation or you can simply write a function that produces appropriate key-value pairs and use `reduce` on that instead.  Another alternative would simply to implement `M` as a sparse matrix using a persistent map.
- The code doesn't filter out 0-valued distances, but this should be trivial to add.

Comment: Thank you Nathan Davis, I was not aware of ```reduce-kv```. I think it does exactly what I need. I will combine it with Charles Duffy's thought to iterate over constrains only - it will save a lot of iterations over unconstrained points, thus going from O(N^2) to O(N). Just out of curiosity, apart from implementing IKVReduce protocol, what would be the other way to generate key-values as you suggested? The matrix is just vector of vectors, so without creating a type of my own I can only iterate over rows that way.

Comment: `IKVReduce` is implemented for vectors.  So you could just use a nested pair of `reduce-kv` calls -- one for each matrix dimension.  Alternatively, you could use a pair of nested `for`s over the `range` of each dimension and generate a sequence of `[i j d]` tuples.  In general, any way of generating a sequence of tuples for all the interesting matrix coordinates will work.  Let me know if you want more detail, and I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Yes, nested ```reduce-kv``` calls came to my mind first thing. I was just wondering if there was a way to pass the generated tuples as key argument to the reducer function directly.

Comment: @waechtertroll, I'm not sure what you mean.